# How to make it appear an image is being covered by content as user scrolls?

Tags: css

You can an example of this at https://www.wiseguypizza.com/ . As you can see their layout is

*image*

*content*

*image*

*content*

*image*

*content*.

As you scroll down it appears the first image you are leaving is being covered by the content and as you continue scrolling it appears that the next image you see is being uncovered as you leave the content. What CSS properties are used to achieve this?

Comment: There are tons  of ways to achieve this, but searching for **"parallax"** should be enough to get you up and running.

Comment: @TylerRoper Cool! Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted the simplest possible approach to this effect (page scrolls over image without image moving), you could just use [`background-attachment: fixed`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp) for the image, and then have the text divs scroll overtop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is a parallax effect.
You can use a simple framework to achieve it, in order to simplify the process.
Here you can find a simple page with the effect you need.
I used **[Materialize](https://materializecss.com/)**, you just have to import JS and CSS (in your source code or from the CDN).

Here's the working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/vPajpG).

Here's the code, you have to add the classes "*parallax-container*" and "*parallax*" to the containers that wraps the image you want to *move* on page scroll and the framework will do the rest!

```
  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552751857-21e31f44fe73?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1344&q=80" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Parallax Page Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="black" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link #5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552751857-21e31f44fe73?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1344&q=80" alt="Unsplashed background img 1"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 center">
          <h3><i class="mdi-content-send green-text"></i></h3>
          <h4>Section Title</h4>
          <p class="left-align light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque id nunc nec volutpat. Etiam pellentesque tristique arcu, non consequat magna fermentum ac. Cras ut ultricies eros. Maecenas eros justo, ullamcorper a sapien id, viverra ultrices eros. Morbi sem neque, posuere et pretium eget, bibendum sollicitudin lacus. Aliquam eleifend sollicitudin diam, eu mattis nisl maximus sed. Nulla imperdiet semper molestie. Morbi massa odio, condimentum sed ipsum ac, gravida ultrices erat. Nullam eget dignissim mauris, non tristique erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496088285923-2bcbf1ba3f62?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="Unsplashed background img 2"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 center">
          <h3><i class="mdi-content-send green-text"></i></h3>
          <h4>Section Title</h4>
          <p class="left-align light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque id nunc nec volutpat. Etiam pellentesque tristique arcu, non consequat magna fermentum ac. Cras ut ultricies eros. Maecenas eros justo, ullamcorper a sapien id, viverra ultrices eros. Morbi sem neque, posuere et pretium eget, bibendum sollicitudin lacus. Aliquam eleifend sollicitudin diam, eu mattis nisl maximus sed. Nulla imperdiet semper molestie. Morbi massa odio, condimentum sed ipsum ac, gravida ultrices erat. Nullam eget dignissim mauris, non tristique erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545960696-624e0d91b52b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1491&q=80" alt="Unsplashed background img 3"></div>
  </div>

  <footer class="black">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Title</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation nisi.</p>


        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Title</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Title</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      &copy; Copyright
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
      $(function(){

        $('.parallax').parallax();

      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!